# Set up Cloud Firestore/NoSQL data structure

Tags: android, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an android app where people can store books information and personal notes about book they read. I am currently using a SQLite database but want to use firebase´s cloud firestore so that users can view other people´s books (and notes if allowed). I have never used a NoSQL database nor Firebase before and dont know how to strucure my data. Personal notes are in a differnet collection because it can contain a long text and i only display it ocationally.

After some research I came up with amodel but I am not sure that it is the best solution.

When you log in you see all your books (without notes) if you click a book you see the notes. You can search for other users and see what books they have (if they set the book to public)
[image]

Comment: That structure sounds reasonable for the use-case you described. But beyond that it is hard to give a recommendation, since in NoSQL databases the best structure largely depends on the use-cases of your app. So instead, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) for a good introduction.